# Request Access Token using refresh token with IdentityModel 4.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identitymodel

I am using IdentityModel 4.1.1 for OAuth2.0
Now here I stucked during create instance of TokenClient, which is used to request new access token using refresh token.

Here's the my code what I am doing,

```
TokenClientOptions clientOptions = new TokenClientOptions();
clientOptions.ClientId = _configDetails.Where(x => x.Key == "ClientId").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
clientOptions.ClientSecret = _configDetails.Where(x => x.Key == "ClientSecret").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

//Create token client object object
var tokenClient = new TokenClient("?",clientOptions); //Here I need help what I have to pass as first parameter?


TokenResponse refereshtokenCallResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(token.RefreshToken);
```

Below TokenClient Class provided by IdentityModel4.1.1 pkg,

```
public class TokenClient
{
    public TokenClient(HttpMessageInvoker client, TokenClientOptions options);
    public TokenClient(Func<HttpMessageInvoker> client, TokenClientOptions options);

    public Task<TokenResponse> RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(string code, string redirectUri, string codeVerifier = null, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    public Task<TokenResponse> RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(string scope = null, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    public Task<TokenResponse> RequestDeviceTokenAsync(string deviceCode, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    public Task<TokenResponse> RequestPasswordTokenAsync(string userName, string password = null, string scope = null, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    public Task<TokenResponse> RequestRefreshTokenAsync(string refreshToken, string scope = null, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    public Task<TokenResponse> RequestTokenAsync(string grantType, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

As above class represent need to pass HttpMessageInvoker as first parameter, but I fully blanked about it.
I also referred IdentityModel [document](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but didn't get any clue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass as an argument an HttpClient, with an already set up BaseUrl.

Take a look at the tests from [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/master/test/UnitTests/TokenClientRequestTests.cs), to see how it is constructed.

Edit: To clear up any confusion, [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) has HttpMessageInvoker as a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Code example:

```
TokenClient tokenClient = new TokenClient(new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(tokenEndpoint) }, new TokenClientOptions { ClientId = "clientId", ClientSecret = "clientSecret" });
```

where tokenEndpoint is typically found in the discovery document:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(authority);
var tokenEndpoint = disco.TokenEndpoint;
```